# Cannot run executable with Travis-CI - Not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: ubuntu, github, qt5, travis-ci, qtserialport

I have been trying to figure out how to make Travis-CI build a QT5-only app.

I has to be Qt5, and include the QSerialPort module, so the stock Ubuntu version is not available (Missing QSerialPort).  I installed Qt 5.x onto a 12.04 Ubuntu VM, tar'd up the files into something I placed into another repo, but when I download and extract the Qt5 executables (qmake + sources, etc), I cannot run them, even though qmake is found in the $PATH.

The code is all posted on https://github.com/npotts/QuteSerial.

.travis.yml

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - gcc

before_install:
  - wget https://github.com/npotts/Qt5-Travis-CI/raw/master/Qt5.txz
  - tar xfp Qt5.txz -C ${HOME}

install:
  - sudo apt-get update -q
  - sudo apt-get install build-essential

script:
  - export PATH="${HOME}/Qt5.3.2/bin:${PATH}"
  - which qmake
  - uname -a
  - qmake --version
  - pwd
  - ls *
  - ls -alh ${HOME}/Qt5.3.2/*
  - ../../Qt5.3.2/bin/qmake
  - vendor/../../Qt5.3.2/bin/qmake
  - make -j$(nproc)
```

Build Errors: 
https://travis-ci.org/npotts/QuteSerial/builds/38996355

Comment: What platform and architecture are the binaries compiled for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but this `before_install` script is what I use to install Qt5 on Travis CI from the Ubuntu repositories.

It's important that the `apt-get` commands are used as is; dependencies don't resolve correctly so I am manually fixing them.

```
before_install:
- sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe"
- sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main"
- sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
- sudo apt-key update
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install qt5-default qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools qtchooser qttools5-dev qtbase5-dev libgles2-mesa-dev libqt5gui5 libqt5serialport5-dev libqt5printsupport5 libqt5widgets5 libgles2-mesa libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libpango-1.0-0
- sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libudev-dev
```

Comment: This fixed it.  It does appear to be a bit hackish, and takes a while to install all the deps, but it does fix the original problem.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I hope that they bring Travis forward to a newer Ubuntu soon so that Qt5 is a more pleasant experience. =P

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the archive you're downloading, and it seems that the binaries in it are compiled for 32 bit architecture. The Travis CI environment is 64 bit, and you will need to provide binaries compiled for 64 bit to make them work.

The error you're seeing is a bit confusing, but it's a common one to see when a binary's compilation target doesn't match the architecture it's running on.

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if that was the case, but I was not seeing any standard errors I am used to.  Im going to try to fix it via QT and then attempt this (more sloppy) solution